# mysql dump with and without absolute path behaves differently when dealing with export destination

Tags: mysql

if i run the following;

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump --all-databases -u root > /newbackup/mysql/alldatabases1.sql
```

it doesnt work and tells me file doesnt exist

> -bash: /newbackup/mysql/alldatabasesss.sql: No such file or directory

but if i run it like this

```
mysqldump --all-databases -u root > /newbackup/mysql/alldatabases1.sql
```

it works fine and creates the file

the reason for me adding the absolute path to the application was to add it into cron

tried the two command lines, were expecting them both to behave the same.

Comment: Output redirection is done by the shell, `mysqldump` has nothing to do with it. If the directory exists, I suspect that filename is a symlink to a nonexisting directory. It's trying to write to the target of the symlink.

Comment: The error can't depend on how you're naming `mysqldump` -- the error happens when the shell performs the output redirection, before it tries to run the program.

Comment: The filename in the error message is not the same as in the command. One is `alldatabases1.sql`, the other is `alldatabasesss.sql`

Comment: ignore that, i tried different file name to see the outcome but was the same, there is no symbolic link, the directory is correct and exists @Barmar

Comment: I still can't think of any way that the way you reference `mysqldump` can affect the file you're redirecting to. Do you have the same problem if you use `echo` vs. `/bin/echo`?

Comment: What shell are you using?